# Grails Spring Security Shiro, how do you refresh permissions without having to logout and re-login?

Tags: grails, spring-security, shiro

I am working on a Grails 3 project that is using Spring Security Shiro for authentication and authorization. Permissions are only refreshed on login. Is there a way to manually refresh permissions? Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `reauthenticate()` method. The [documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/) (Section 6.2.10) explains how this is used, but here is a quick example:

`def springSecurityService 
...
def currentUsername = springSecurityService.principal.username
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(currentUsername)`

Comment: `reauthenticate()` isn't working 100%, is there something in addition to this? It may be that I am using a custom permissions resolver.

Comment: You may want to include more information then about your custom permission resolver and the code within it. Further describe what happens when you try using `reauthenticate()` and why it's not meeting your needs. The more detail (and code) you can provide in your question the more likely it is that we can answer it.

Comment: I set `grails.plugin.springsecurity.shiro.useCache = false`, this took care of the issue. Thank you!